# Connecting visual c++ to an online database

Tags: mysql, database, visual-c++

I am working on an app in visual c++ which requires data to be accessed from a database which can be edited so that every time there is a modification to the data I do not have to resend the app as it will automatically update, it is also required that this is a desktop app.

I am currently using MySql however for this to run constantly I will be needing a server which for a single simple app wont really be worth purchasing, so I started thinking of alternative methods and thought to myself there must be some method of reading directly from a website or online database, am I correct in thinking this? If so could someone please explain how I would achieve this?

Also, I have purchased phpmyadmin in the past so if there is any way I could connect my visual c++ app to a database from this then that would be great.

EDIT: Note, this app relies almost entirely on the database as it is just 3 combo box's and one text field all of that values for which come from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following response is assuming that by `online` you mean on the web.

You cannot exactly 'connect' to an online database with C++ (or anything outside of that server hosting the database).

What I would do is create some PHP API's that you can POST to with [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) via C++. You can both send and receive data this way.